# How to properly link libraries with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have 2 libraries made from scratch in c, `vector.h` and `string.h` with the source file `string.c` (the `vector.h` only has define directives, no need for source file), and used the `#pragma once` directive so that the header files would only be included one time. The string library uses the vector library, and then both are included in `main.c`.

With that setup, i ran into two problems:

- if i simply did `gcc main.c -o build/main.exe`, it couldn't find the function definitions in `string.c` for the function declarations in `string.h` (undefined reference to `stringFunction')
- if i first compiled the source files into objects, and then compiled them into the executable (`gcc -c string/string.c -o build/obj/string.o`, `gcc -c main.c -o build/obj/main.o`, `gcc -o build/main.exe build/obj/main.o build/obj/string.o`, `./build/main.exe`), it said there were multiple definitions of the same functions (build/obj/string.o: in function `vectorCreate_String':
  string.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `vectorCreate_String'; build/obj/main.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here)

Folder structure:

```
PROJECT
    - string
        - string.c
        - string.h
    - vector
        - vector.h
    - main.c
```

`vector.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEFINE_VECTOR(type) typedef struct { \
    unsigned int size; \
    size_t bytesize; \
    type *data; \
} Vector_##type; \
Vector_##type *vectorCreate_##type(unsigned int initialSize, type *initialElements) { \
    Vector_##type *v = (Vector_##type*)malloc(sizeof(Vector_##type)); \
    v->size = initialSize; \
    v->bytesize = initialSize * sizeof(type); \
    v->data = (type*)malloc(v->bytesize); \
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<initialSize; i++) v->data[i] = initialElements[i]; \
    return v; \
} \
void vectorPush_##type(Vector_##type *v, type element) { \
    v->size++; \
    v->bytesize += sizeof(type); \
    v->data = (type*)realloc(v->data, v->bytesize); \
    v->data[v->size-1] = element; \
} \
void vectorFree_##type(Vector_##type *v) { \
    free(v->data); \
    free(v); \
} \
Vector_##type *vectorSlice_##type(Vector_##type *v, unsigned int start, unsigned int end) { \
    Vector_##type *slice = (Vector_##type*)malloc(sizeof(Vector_##type)); \
    slice->size = end - start; \
    slice->bytesize = slice->size * sizeof(type); \
    slice->data = (type*)malloc(slice->bytesize); \
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<slice->size; i++) slice->data[i] = v->data[start + i]; \
    return slice; \
}

#define Vector(type) Vector_##type
#define vectorCreate(type, initialSize, initialElements) vectorCreate_##type(initialSize, initialElements)
#define vectorPush(type, vector, element) vectorPush_##type(vector, element)
#define vectorFree(type, vector) vectorFree_##type(vector)
#define vectorSlice(type, vector, start, end) vectorSlice_##type(vector, start, end)
```

`string.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "../vector/vector.h"

typedef struct {
    unsigned int length;
    char *str;
} String;


DEFINE_VECTOR(String);


String *stringCreate(char *str);

String *stringAppend(String *string, char *str);

void stringFree(String *string);

String *stringSlice(String *string, unsigned int start, unsigned int end);

Vector(String) *stringSplit(String *string, char *delimiter);
```

`string.c`

```c
#include "string.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

String *stringCreate(char *str) {
    String *string = malloc(sizeof(String));
    string->length = strlen(str);
    string->str = malloc(string->length + 1);
    strcpy(string->str, str);
    return string;
}

String *stringAppend(String *string, char *str) {
    string->length += strlen(str);
    string->str = realloc(string->str, string->length + 1);
    strcat(string->str, str);
    return string;
}

void stringFree(String *string) {
    free(string->str);
    free(string);
}

String *stringSlice(String *string, unsigned int start, unsigned int end) {
    String *newString;
    newString->length = end - start;
    newString->str = malloc(newString->length + 1);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<newString->length; i++) newString->str[i] = string->str[start + i];
    newString->str[newString->length] = '\0';
    return newString;
}

// not implemented yet
Vector(String) *stringSplit(String *string, char *delimiter) {
    return NULL;
}
```

`main.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "./string/string.h"

// stuff to test if everything is working properly
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Vector(String) *strings = vectorCreate(String, 0, NULL);
    vectorPush(String, strings, *stringCreate("Hello"));
    vectorPush(String, strings, *stringCreate("World"));
    printf("%s %s\n", strings->data[0].str, strings->data[1].str);
    vectorFree(String, strings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend `gcc -E` and looking at the files to see whatever mess the macros made. I'd recommend rethinking the macro idea too, but now that you've done it you may as well figure out how to make it work.

Comment: `string.h` is instantiating function definitions, which are present in both `string.o` and `main.o`.   Instead of putting the invocations of DEFINE_VECTOR in `string.h`, you should put them in `string.c`

Comment: @WilliamPursell i know that, i just don't know how to resolve it as vector is used in the header file as the return type of `stringSplit`, so i can't move the definitions in the source file (also i tried to make the vector functions extern, thinking that would use the declarations in the header instead of copying them in each source file that uses it, didn't work)

Comment: @RetiredNinja the macros were the only way i managed to implement pseudo-generics; a thing that for sure didn't help was that i couldn't find gcc flags and their meaning, something like a man page would've been very helpful, but gcc's man page has flags and options but doesn't explain what they do

Comment: In a pinch you can make all the function definitions provided by the macro `static`.

Comment: @n.m. thank you, that did work, forgot about static as i haven't used it for functions before, only local variables and class members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "function declaration" is usually put into a .h file.

A "function definition" is usually put into a .c file.

`DEFINE_VECTOR` provides function definitions and you use it in `string.h`.
Which means the function `vectorCreate_String()` for example is defined both in `string.c` and `main.c` due to both including `string.h`.

I suggest you add another macro in `vector.h` that only generates function declarations and move that typedef struct from `DEFINE_VECTOR` to that macro. Use that macro in `string.h`, and then use `DEFINE_VECTOR` in `string.c` to provide definitions for the declared functions in `string.h`.

Comment: That did work, and it seems like good practice to separate declarations and definitions into headers, respectively source files